# How to cast a String to a Date for a CriteriaBuilder Predicate

Tags: java, date, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'm using CriteriaBuilder to create a search for our application. One of our tables has a column that is used to store multiple data types.

(The implementation is similar to Option 2 of the answer given in this question: [Sane way to store different data types within same column in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233570/sane-way-to-store-different-data-types-within-same-column-in-postgres))

Essentially what I want to do is simple:

`Predicate datePredicate = cb.lessThan(field.get(MyTable_.value), new Date());`

But, `value` is a `String` and cannot be compared properly to a `Date`.

My question is, is there some way to convert/cast the string into a date for comparison?

Comment: What is the date format that will be saved into a string field?

Comment: Something like this `16/08/2016`.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way you can cast a string field for the sake of comparison. You have to change the `value` field to type of date.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible via a cast, but you can use SimpleDateFormat to parse a String to a date:

```
String date1AsString = "20160101";
Date date1AsDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(date1AsString);
```

Comment: The problem with using a Formatter such as this is that `field.get(MyTable_.value)` is not technically providing a `String` but a `Path<String>`. Unless I'm missing something, this isn't going to work.

Comment: Sorry I thought your question is how to convert a String to a date. Which Path class are you using?

Comment: It's from `javax.persistence.criteria`.